# when including() or require() do I always have to use ../../ relative to my file? Is there a simple way?

Tags: php, path, include, directory, require

I'm building a web app that has php files spread out through different directories, so a typical file may have several includes. All these files everywhere.

a php file may look like this:

```
include('../../some.php');
require('../../some.php');
```

and in another file you may have something like this:

```
 include('../../../../some.php');
require('../../../../some.php');
```

point being, this can get a little bit out of hand, and somewhat difficult to keep track of. Is there a way I can do this so that I don't need to `../../..` all the time?

I tried doing this:

```
include('http://www.mywebsite.com/some.php');
require('http://www.mywebsite.com/some.php');
```

but it doesn't seem to work, but what's funny is that I won't get a PHP error when I use require, only a 
`call to function x() error, function or object doesn't exist` type error. It never said anything about the file not existing. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not trust `$_SERVER` variables. In some environments they can be set/altered by the user making the request. It's much better to define the base path manually in your index/bootstrap file and use it when needed.

```
define('SYSTEM_PATH', __DIR__ . '/');
```

or on version of PHP before 5.3 you can do this

```
define('SYSTEM_PATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

Now you can always know the path to your files.

```
require(SYSTEM_PATH . 'lib/class.php');
```

Both `__DIR__` and `__FILE__` are **safe** constants set by PHP and can be trusted.

You can autoload classes like this:

```
function __autoload($class_name)
{
    require SYSTEM_PATH . strtolower($class_name) . '.php';
}
```

In other news, I can't ever think of a *good* use for `include()`. If you need to use include you are doing something wrong.

Comment: "In some environments they can be set/altered by the user making the request." Can you expand on this a little more?

Comment: How else would I include files into another PHP doc? What would be the right way of going about this?

Comment: Thank you Xeoncross, I'm gonna prepare my app to use the `_autoload` function. I did some research and really liked what it did. I know I didn't put too many details on my question, but the `_autoload()` function pretty  much does what a part of my app does. The only thing is that I have some functions out there too, and I'm not sure that this will work, though I'm sure there is something similar to it.

Comment: @Xeoncross, Why is it bad to use include? In my case, I've built a library of functions for an e-commerce website, and certain functions need to be used on more than one page. So whenever I need to use certain functions, I include that library file, example 'library/products.php' has functions to create/update/retrieve/delete products from the database. It's required on every page which needs to show products.

Comment: Also, I will use `if(!defined(SYSTEM_PATH)) define(...)` at the top of every page, or is it better to redirect the user to the index page where the constant is defined?

Comment: @Ozzy, the different between `include` and `require` is that if include fails - *the script keeps running*! **That is very bad!** If a file you need access to fails to load, it's much better for the script to just end right there otherwise you might open yourself up to an attack. Other than that, you can use require/include for the same things so just use require. In addition, if you are loading/requiring a script *multiple times* you are probably doing something wrong. Instead the script should be loaded once, and then the functions/classes in it can be used for the rest of the request.

Comment: @Ozzy, forcing all requests to go through an `index.php` is called a "Front-controller" pattern. Basically, there is only one way into an application and it helps to make sure that all pages have the same bootstrap code loading them. Almost all frameworks and CMS's work this way. In every other PHP file you should add a `<?php defined(SYSTEM_PATH) OR die('Cannot access this file directly');` to the top of the file so that people don't access files they aren't supposed to.

Comment: However, if you have multiple `.php` files that do different things then I would recommend making a `init.php` file in the project root directory and defining your system path, database connection, and other shared assets there and including that file on all your pages so they all have access to them.

Comment: @Xeoncross Ohh right, when I said include I did mean require, I am using `require_once` for all of those scripts. So thats wrong - and I'm supposed to wrap the functions in a class, and load the class once at the start? And I wasn't sure if that was normal - the "front-controller" pattern, but that's what I will implement, so thanks.

Comment: @Ozzy, you can use functions all over your codebase once you require the file - you don't need to require it multiple times. However, grouping functions by a class would help you organize your code better and allow extra OOD features like inheritance. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/create-your-first-tiny-mvc-boilerplate-with-php/

Comment: @Xeoncross thanks that video was very helpful! you should've posted it in your original answer.

Answer (score 1):

this is what include paths were invented for. if there is a folder outside of your public folder that you use often, make an include path leading to it. this way you can treat it as if it were in the same folder as everything else.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

Better than that however, create a class autoloader...

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/inc/connect.php');
```

This will bring you to the document root, then build the rest from there...

Comment: the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT]` variable is automatically set to my URL? (`http://www.mywebsite.com`) or do I have to declare it?

Comment: It's set by the server. You shouldn't have to change anything. To test it, simply `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` to see the result.

Comment: @FelipeTadeo PHP sees the filesystem of your server, so an include path might look like `/home/user/public_html/inc/connect.php`. Only the outside world works with URLs like `http://example.com`, and at that point all PHP has been processed. If you could include URLs you would be bringing in PHP from other websites, which would be very dangerous (besides the fact that it wouldn't work at all).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the include path in php.ini, or you can change the working directory with `chdir`. I prefer both, to be on the safe side, but this works just fine:

```
chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

Now you can include your files as if the current one were in the root folder.